# FileStream, read data chunk from big file. Filesize bigger than int. How to set the offset?

Tags: c#, file, stream, filestream

FileStream.Read() is defined as:

```
public override int Read(
    byte[] array,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

How can I read some bytes from an offset bigger than int.MaxValue?

Let's say I have a very big file and I want to read 100MB starting from position 3147483648.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `offset` here is the offset **in the array** at which to start writing. In your case, just set:

```
stream.Position = 3147483648;
```

and then use `Read()`. The `offset` is most commonly used when you know you need to read [n] bytes:

```
int toRead = 20, bytesRead;
while(toRead > 0 && (bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, toRead)) > 0)
{
    toRead -= bytesRead;
    offset += bytesRead;
}
if(toRead > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
```

this will read exactly 20 bytes into `buffer` (or throw an exception). Note that `Read()` is not guaranteed to read all the required data in one go, hence a loop incrementing an offset is usually required.

Comment: But what happens when offset goes above int.MaxValue? How would you handle that?

Comment: @tayl0rs since the max array size for the buffer would be exceeded at that point, it is a moot concern. Even with very-large-array support enabled, you can't exceed that in any dimension; see "remarks" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx (and keep in mind: the offset relates to the array, not the stream)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx the `offset` parameter is an `offset inside the byte[] array`:

> array
>       Type: System.Byte[]
>       When this method returns, contains the specified byte array with
>   the values between offset and (offset + count - 1) replaced by the
>   bytes read from the current source.
>
> offset
>       Type: System.Int32
>       The byte offset in array at which the read bytes will be placed.
>
> count
>       Type: System.Int32
>       The maximum number of bytes to read.

`Read()` just reads from the current positon which happens to be a `long` and should be set before calling `Read()` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx